# Move Hair with Armature

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I am trying to animate my character right now but whenever I move the head the hair particle system doesn't move with it. Is there a way to make it so that whenever the head moves the hair follows?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I figured out that it was as simple as putting hair dynamics on and making the armature modifier be above the particle modifier.